# Error while executing grunt command

Tags: gruntjs

While trying to execute grunt command.

I have used yeoman, bower, generator-angular and grunt with nodejs in windows 7.

Everything worked fine. And I have added font-awesome with bower-install, and to update my html I executed grunt wiredep.

it throws the following error.

[image]

Also my bower components are outside app folder, But in index file it started with bower_compontents/jquery/dist/jquery.js instead ../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the node modules.

I just deleted it and executed npm install again. All worked well :-)

**Change bower_components path**
in .bowerrc file, I have changed the directory path. :-)